# Can not pass the model back to controller from view in ASP.NET MVC. Model is null when received

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two model classes

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public SubItem SubObject { get; set; }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Work { get; set; }
}
```

From my code I have something similar to this

```
public IActionResult ViewAndSend()
{
        Item item = new Item
        {
            Name = "MyName",
            SubObject = new SubItem
            {
                Age = 29,
                Work = "Microsoft and google"
            },
        };

    return View(item);
}
```

and my `ViewAndSend.cshtml` looks like this

```
@model TestNavigation.Models.Item

<h2>ViewAndSend example</h2>
<p>@(String.Format("{0} {1}", "Name", Model.Name))</p>
<p>@(String.Format("{0} {1}", "Age", Model.SubObject.Age))</p>
<p>@(String.Format("{0} {1}", "Work", Model.SubObject.Work))</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SendSubItem", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubObject.Age)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SubObject.Work)

    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
}
```

My `SendSubItem` method looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendSubItem(SubItem subItem)
{
        int age = subItem.Age; //age is 0
        var work = subItem.Work; // work is null

        return View();
}
```

The `ViewAndSend.cshtml` prints the correct values. However the `SendSubItem` method gets an object with 0 as `Age` and null for `Work`.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try with the `[FromBody]` attribute. `public IActionResult SendSubItem([FromBody] SubItem subItem)`

Comment: It did not work according to your suggestion

Comment: Use input hidden html tag with exact values of your field names for name

Comment: And even better way is to use Ajax to post back form for you and you can create custom objects to pass to method

Comment: And answer to your question send data as query string and it will work

Comment: <script>$(document).ready($('.your class for submit button').onclick({$.ajax({method:'post',url:'/controller/action?firstField=@firstvalue&secondField&@secondValue'});}););</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Item as the receiving type.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendSubItem(Item item)
{
    int age = item.SubObject.Age; 
    var work = item.SubObject.Work; 
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Form only post back inner object @mj1313

Comment: Your solutions work. Is it possible to send another type for example only SubObject from the view to controller?

Comment: Yes, you can use Html.hidden and set its name as same as it in the SubItem:@Html.Hidden("Age", Model.SubObject.Age)
    @Html.Hidden("Work", Model.SubObject.Work)